# how to prevent overriding text on image while reducing width of screen

Tags: html, css

"I am reducing width of screen but text of paragraph overrides the image, what changes should I do to prevent overriding text "

"This is for a part website building , I tried to play with some css3 properties here in code but couldnt resolve problem "

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #facilities{
            height: 430px;
            background: #fff;
        }
        #facilities .facility-img {
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
        }
        #facilities .facility-img img{
            width: 600px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 30px 70px;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info{
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info h1{
            color: #333;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info  p{
            color: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="facilities">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="facility-img ">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170979/pexels-photo-1170979.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="facility-photo">
            </div>
            <div class="facility-info">
                <h1>In a hospital , half of the patients get better food than at home.</h1>
                <p>~Gerhard KocSher</p>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Sit autem ducimus delectus nam aut neque vitae, ab repellendus, qui, quibusdam eum commodi sunt? Non veniam quos illo, assumenda doloremque sit possimus sunt architecto quo neque doloribus provident consequuntur eius error.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `width: 600px` to `width: 100%` on yor image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #facilities{
            height: 430px;
            background: #fff;
        }
        #facilities .facility-img {
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
        }
        #facilities .facility-img img{
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 30px 70px;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info{
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info h1{
            color: #333;
        }
        #facilities .facility-info  p{
            color: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="facilities">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="facility-img ">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170979/pexels-photo-1170979.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="facility-photo">
            </div>
            <div class="facility-info">
                <h1>In a hospital , half of the patients get better food than at home.</h1>
                <p>~Gerhard KocSher</p>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Sit autem ducimus delectus nam aut neque vitae, ab repellendus, qui, quibusdam eum commodi sunt? Non veniam quos illo, assumenda doloremque sit possimus sunt architecto quo neque doloribus provident consequuntur eius error.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

You need to set your image width to 100% so that it stretches or shrinks according to its parent width (the div). The div parent is set to 40% of its parent container, which is the window.

That being said, your padding is still in "px" and so not proportional to your window. When you shrink your window a lot, you will end up with lots of padding compared to the window size. Think about changing those values too.